# Test Django Mock - check that function/method is called

Tags: django, mocking, callable

I want to check that **do_a** calls **do_b**. I'm doing like this:

The code:

```
def do_a(...):
    ...
    do_b(...)
    ...
```

The test:

```
def test_do_a(self):
        ...

        with patch('...do_b', new_callable=do_nothing()) as mock_do_b:
            do_a(...)

        mock_do_b.assert_called_once_with(...)
```

And do_nothing:

```
def do_nothing():
     pass
```

This is working fine but I had to use do_nothing() which I find hacky. Is there a way to make the same test without the extra useless function do_nothing()?

Comment: You could use a lambda instead of a callable `lambda : True` but lambda appears more hackish ;)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that as well. I might just write patch_with_nothing(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use patch as a decorator

```
@patch('...do_b')
def test_do_a(self, mock_do_b):
    do_a(...)
    mock_do_b.assert_called_once_with(...)
```

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't remove the need for do_nothing() or lambda: True.

Comment: Maybe that was a version issue - just add the same issue and this is working. Also, `return_value` instead of `new_callable` does the trick.